# How to escape HTML in display text within rectangle node

Tags: d3-org-chart

I am using the d3-org library for creating a chart and would like to be able to add images or break the text over multiple lines.

The text within the rectangle seems to escape any html and was wondering how this could be overridden?

I have tried removing the replace commands within the js file but that doesn't seem to have made any difference